# Why does setting the time from python using timedatectl set UTC time while using the command line sets local time?

Tags: python, linux, time, timezone

I am trying to set the system date/time on ubuntu server from python 3 by running a shell script to which I pass a date/time string of the form "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss". The script passes this string to timedatectl to set the time.

The python call looks like this:

```
os.system('sudo %s/settime.sh "%s"' % (Constants.ScriptDirectory, dt))
```

where dt in this case is "2019-09-12 07:00:00"

The shell script is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
timedatectl set-ntp no
timedatectl set-time "$1"
```

When I log the actual command called from python I see what I expect:

```
sudo /home/user/dev/web/sh/settime.sh "2019-09-12 07:00:00"
```

The problem is this: The system time is changed, but it sets it as the UTC time (ie. 2019-09-12 07:00:00 UTC) and the time reported by running date is out by the timezone delta. However, if I run the exact same command as above from the command line the time is correctly set in the local timezone, rather than as UTC.

This discrepancy occurs even if I include a call in python to use timedatectl to explicitly set the timezone prior to the call to set the time.

I'm baffled. Why should the effect be different?

For reference, I am using Django 2.2.3 and running the development server. Is it possible that the server is messing with the timezone when it runs python?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the answer via an indirect route.

The Django settings.py file had

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Changing the value to the local timezone, or having it load dynamically resolved the problem.